# Getting Custom Fields of Object with Javascript Button

Tags: soql, javascript, custom-object, custom-button, custom-field

I have a custom Object called Command (Command__c) containing the custom fields Date (Date) and Email Template (Linked to the Object Email Template below)
I also have a custom object Email Template (Email_Template__c) containing the field Name and the Custom Field Content (Content__c)

I use a Custom OnClick Javascript Button to get informations. But here I need to get the Content field of the Email template of a Command.

```
var email = sforce.connection.query("Select Name FROM Email_Template__c WHERE Id = '{!Command__c.Email_TemplateId__c}'").getArray("records")[0];
alert("{!Command__c.Name} Created by {!Command__c.CreatedBy}\n {!Command__c.Email_Template__c} ({!Command__c.Email_TemplateId__c}) : " + email)
```

I used this to get the object i needed. But the Content field is seems to be missing.

I also used this :

```
var result = sforce.connection.describeSObject("Email_Template__c");
var txt ="";
alert(result.label + " : " + result.name + " : " + result);

txt+="---------- fields ---------\n";
for (var i=0; i<result.fields.length; i++) {
  var field = result.fields[i];
  txt+=field.name + " : " + field.label + " : " + field.length + " : \n";
}
alert(txt);

txt="---------- child relationships ---------\n";
for (var i=0; i<result.childRelationships.length; i++) {
  var cr = result.childRelationships[i];
  txt+=cr.field + " : " + cr.childSObject + "\n";
}
alert(txt);

txt="---------- record type info ----------\n";
for (var i=0; i<result.recordTypeInfos.length; i++) {
  var rt = result.recordTypeInfos[i];
  txt+=rt.name + "\n";
}
alert(txt);
```

And saw the data. No Custom field either. How can I get the custom field ?